# Having problem in scaffold in ruby using sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 5 and while in the concept of scaffold, when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (
>
> Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
>
> bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
>
> ):

```
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:576:in `check_pending!'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Also the schema.rb is empty

Comment: Have you tried this command :- **bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development**

Comment: Just do what it says, did you already do it? That might be a problem.

Comment: Yes I've done it but still the problem remains.

Comment: Also schema.rb is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was having this problem because I was running all the commands only inside my project instead of going to **bin** directory.

So first go to bin directory and then all the commands will work

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may have inadvertently changed a migration file name or something caused the migrations table to get out of sync. If you are ok with starting over I would suggest the following.

```
bin/rails db:drop
bin/rails db:create
bin/rails db:migrate
```

See if that gets you past that error.

Comment: Does `bin/rails db:migrate:status` give you any useful info?

Comment: No it doesn't have